# Add-Opens Java Jar Manifest attribute

Tags: java, jar, manifest, java-platform-module-system

What's the correct way to add `Add-Opens` attribute in java jar Manifest? I have added the attribute and it appears like this in MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Add-Opens: java.base/sun.security.ssl
```

The doc: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Packaging:-Modular-JAR-files mentions

> A `<module>/<package>` pair in the value of an Add-Opens attribute has the same meaning as the command-line option `--add-opens <module>/<package>=ALL-UNNAMED"`.

Providing argument via command line works as expected, however, adding it as an attribute in manifest doesn't.

Is this the correct way to add `Add-Opens` attribute?

Comment: Do you start your application with `java -jar thisjarfile.jar`?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yes, I run the application with `java -jar thisjarfile.jar`. When I run it like : `java -jar thisjarfile.jar --add-opens <module>/<package>=ALL-UNNAMED` it works, however I want to add it as Manifest attribute.

Comment: If you add the `Add-Opens` to the manifest file, it looks like `Add-Opens: java.base/java.util my.module/my.package`. The XML syntax that you provided is not for a manifest file itself, but most probably for a tool that generates a manifest file. Without knowing that tool (you should name it at least) nobody can tell whether you got it right or not.

Comment: Try to check the contents of the generated `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with a zip extractor of your choice.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn:

Manifest has: `Add-Opens: java.base/sun.security.ssl`

Comment: @tquadrat: I have edited the post to highlight how it appears in MANIFEST.MF file.